# searching for provabiliy logic books

Tags: logic, provability

I ve been searching for a while for books about provability logic, though everything that  I found yet seems incomprehensible to me. I have read some first year college courses on naive set theory. Apart from that, I have no training in logic. Could anyone suggest some background or  prerequisite reading? thank you.

Comment: Can you please add some details about what your background is/what year of study you are in/what you have studied before. Then people can make recommendations based on that.

Comment: See [Provability Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/) for bibliography. A possibility is George Boolos, [The Logic of Provability](https://books.google.it/books?id=WekaT3OLoUcC&printsec=frontcover) (1993).

Comment: *Computability and logic*, by Boolos *et al*, is a nice introduction to logic, and has a final chapter on Provability Logic. I highly recommend reading that one before *The Logic of Provability*, which can be a bit daunting.